# Magento Customer Login Issue - Login Page Keeps Reloading On Login

Tags: magento, session, cookies, authentication

So I found several variations of this issue and tried the solutions; none worked.

So customers are not able to login with the correct username and password. The login screen (https://www.example.com/customer/account/login) just refreshes when the credentials are entered correctly -- should redirect to the My Account Dashboard.

The only thing that seems to temporarily work (few hours at a time before the problem comes back) is when we change back and forth the System > Config > Web > Session Cookie Management > Cookie Domain to "https://www.example.com" and ".example.com" Then we flush the Magento Cache and we flush the Storage Cache and refresh the all Cache Types.

After this, Customers can login on Firefox, Safari and IE, but not Chrome (same login page looping issue).

We have exhausted everything we can think of. No errors in the logs and we have the correct getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?> code in the login.phtml files. We are using a custom theme and noticed this problem after migrating the site from Enterprise Edition to Community edition.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any chance you are using Alan Storms commerce bug extension?  If so, grab an up-to-date copy.   There was a bug that was causing this, but Alan got it all patched up.   Another thing I've seen cause this is if you are logging into multiple Magento admins on the same browser.  Seems sometimes the cookies get all skued.  I use chrome develper tools -> resources -> cookies -> clear all   to solve the problem.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, so I'm not using Alan Storm's commerce bug extension so doubt that's it. Also, the problem persists whether I'm logged into Magento's admin panel or not... Just very weird. Can't resolve this issue. Right now it seems to be affecting Chrome login the worst.

Comment: Yea, I would undo any changes you did to the session cookies, flush cache.   Then when you are having this issue, check to see which domain the frontend cookie is set to.   If it's anything other than .yourdomain.com than there is an extension messing with ya.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reading this article and opportunity to post my answer here.

I also faced same problem which AShah faced. I also googleing but did not find such proper result. Finally I removed or clean the session folder (root>var>session) and its works fine for my store.

Hope this trick will solve you. thanks

Answer (score 0):

First check what are the values set for following *path* in *core_config_data*
table

```
web/cookie/cookie_path
web/cookie/cookie_domain
```

Try by replacing any existing value by `NULL`.

Following should be set to 1

```
web/cookie/cookie_httponly
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just tried this, but it didn't work. Same thing persists. Login loop in Chrome and working temporarily in other browsers. Cannot seem to figure out what is causing the issue. It is some combination of session cookie management (cookie domain) and caching...

Comment: @AShah are you using Varsnish Cache on your server? Which version of Magento you are using?

Comment: Sorry, just saw this.. I thought maybe it was Varnish related. Turns out it isn't enabled. Memcached is enabled. We disabled memcached and it had no positive effect on the problem.

Comment: I think it has something to do with magento setting double frontend cookies with different cookie values. If I manually remove the second cookie in my browser, login works. Any idea how to remove a second frontend cookie from being set with a different cookie value?